# Is 'coordination' a countable noun?

Tags: grammar, indefinite-article

> But those productions rely heavily on the Fair use doctrine, an
> important but often wobbly legal standard that allows part of a song
> to be played for limited purposes or on direct coordination of music
> labels, a process that can be prohibitively time-consuming and
> arbitrary.

Is 'coordination' a countable noun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's implicitly defining - for its purposes - "a coordination (of music labels)" to mean a specific combination of music labels, after which it would be reasonable to say things like "two coordinations allow use of song X" (for example, the owning label may have one arrangement with labels A and B, and another with label C).  So, it becomes countable in that context.

https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/coordination.html has a take on this:

> The noun coordination can be countable or uncountable.

> In more general, commonly used, contexts, the plural form will also be coordination.

> However, in more specific contexts, the plural form can also be coordinations e.g. in reference to various types of coordinations or a collection of coordinations.